# Is there a way to scale the curve vertex in 2 axes. like x. y . Not x.y. z

Tags: bezier-curves, curve-modifier

[image]

I want to scale the curve vertex in the x,y axes. Not x,y,z. Something there is no way that I know can do that.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You can scale along XY if you drag the little blue square in the scale gizmo.

Comment: Hello, Louis, if this is a curve's native bevel, no, you can't do it with *Radius*. But if you (_Curve_ modifier) deform a pre-existing mesh strip, then scaling potions of the  mesh in edit mode (with the modifier's Edit Cage switched on for convenience)  will scale the result in curve-space.

Comment: No. I am talking about the alt+s short key to deform one vertex in the curve's native bevel.

Answer (score 2):

When you press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale something, you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to make it scale along XY.